# Loading indicator for Charm menu logout service call

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have logout option in Charm menu in windows 8.1 store app. When user clicks logout option in charm menu I'm hitting service call.

In above case I should show loading progress bar in application screen. My problem is user can be any of the screen in my application

Is there any common way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar functionality in my app. When the button is tapped/clicked (in a FlyOut, not in the Charms directly), a publicly accessible Sub (in a Module e.g.) is executed:

```vb
Public Sub OpenModalBackground(Optional ByVal strProgressText As String = "")
    pupModalBackground = New Popup
    pupModalBackground.IsLightDismissEnabled = False
    pupModalBackground.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width
    pupModalBackground.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height

    Dim foModalBackground As New FlyOuts.ModalBackground
    foModalBackground.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width
    foModalBackground.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height
    foModalBackground.ProgressText = strProgressText
    pupModalBackground.Child = foModalBackground

    pupModalBackground.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 0)
    pupModalBackground.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0)
    pupModalBackground.IsOpen = True
End Sub
```

As you can see a new PopUp is generated, and a "FlyOut" (UserControl) ModalBackground is loaded, which looks like this:

```xml
<Grid Background="#BF000000">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ProgressRing IsActive="True" Foreground="White" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ProgressText}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

it's working well for me.
As far as I've seen there is a new Control FlyOut for Win8.1, so you might use that one instead of a UserControl.

By the way: according to these [Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770544.aspx) you should not execute a direct action from an entry point.

Comment: I'm expecting some thing like stub the progress bar to main Frame so that I can use same on every screen

Comment: I am using that snippet in a settings FlyOut, so wherever you are in the application, you can call that sub OpenModalBackground() and the ProgressRing is shown. It's not somehow connected to the main Frame, but it's available everywhere.
But maybe you mean something else and I am misunderstanding you?